# Rolling Back from current WordPress version to previous one

Tags: wpdb, upgrade

What happens if we rollback from (for example) 3.8 to 3.5.1 and keep the same new DB created by the current version? Will that break anything?

Comment: You might want to consult the [Changelog in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/).

Comment: What's the reason behind rolling back? Plugin comparability? I ask because keeping your wp out of date is not a good idea.

Comment: we will eventually upgrade.. but since our stuff is super customized..we need to do it carefully. This time the upgrade was done by accident ( with just 1 stupid click )

Comment: As I do not know the exact answer to this, a trial and error approach would be okay for you if you can afford some 10 minutes of downtime. Backup your whole installation and Database, and just overwrite the files. If everything works out - nice, if not - restore the old version. This is not a very sophisticated way to approach your situation. You can also duplicate your setup, and try it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can have problems only if database schema changed from older to new version.

To know if the your is the case, you can compare the file `wp-admin/includes/schema.php` for both the versions, see that online [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/schema.php) for 3.8.1 and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/schema.php) for 3.5.1.

Note that a db index change should not beak the site, but it can cause performance issues.

If you think the schemas are compatible, before putting the old files back, I suggest you to also change the option in database pointing to current database schema.

In options table, there's a row with `option_name`: `db_version` and `option_value` that contains the current database schema number, so I suggest to change manually it (using *phpmyadmin* or similar) to the old database version number. To know it, look ad `wp-includes/version.php` file of the older version. As you can see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/version.php#L14), for WP 3.5.1 the version number was **22441** (is 26691 in WP 3.8.1).

As additional suggestion, be sure to have a complete database backup before doing anything.